# How to run foreach loop in jquery for dynamic data in datatables and redirect to details page in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, each, yajra-datatable

I am using yajra datable to fetch all the data from database dynamically using ajax and jquery. I have columns called "Membersid","Role" and so on...now What I want to do is for each value in "Membersid" there should a link which should redirect to details page of that particular membersid.
Here is my route:

```html
Route::resource('/Memberdetails', MemberdetailController::class);
```

and this how my current script looks like..not sure this is correct or not:

```html
$('#members_data').on('click', 'tbody td', function(){
   window.location = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0) a').attr('{{ route('Membersdetails.show') }}');
```

Can someone help me out how to redirect this to Details page of particular membersid

Her is my Controller code:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Models\Memberdetails;
use App\Models\Attrition_correlators;

class CustomSearchController extends Controller
{
    function index(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            if(!empty($request->Business_unit))
            {
                $data = DB::table('memberdetails')
                        ->select('membersid','Role','Region','Orglevel1','Orglevel2','Riskzone','Probablity')
                        ->where('Business_unit',$request->Business_unit)
                        ->where('Orglevel1',$request->Orglevel1)
                        ->where('Role',$request->Role)
                        ->get();
            }
            else
            {
                $data = DB:: table('memberdetails')
                        ->select('membersid','Role','Region','Orglevel1','Orglevel2','Riskzone','Probablity')
                        ->get();
            }
            return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
        }

        $Business_unit_name = DB::table('memberdetails')
                            ->select('Business_unit')
                            ->groupBy('Business_unit')
                            ->orderBy('Business_unit', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $Orglevel1_name = DB::table('memberdetails')
                            ->select('Orglevel1')
                            ->groupBy('Orglevel1')
                            ->orderBy('Orglevel1', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $Role_name = DB::table('memberdetails')
                            ->select('Role')
                            ->groupBy('Role')
                            ->orderBy('Role', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $Memberdetails= new Memberdetails;
        $Memberdetails_list= $Memberdetails::all();
        return view('admin.members.test', compact('Business_unit_name','Orglevel1_name','Role_name','Memberdetails_list'));
    }

     public function show(Memberdetails $Memberdetail)
    {
        $Attrition_correlator = Attrition_correlators::all();
        return view('admin.members.Detailspage',compact('Memberdetail','Attrition_correlator'));
    }
}
```

Here is my View

```html
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
<br/>
<div class="content">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="Business_unit" id="Business_unit" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Business Unit</option>
                @foreach($Business_unit_name as $Bu)
                <option value="{{ $Bu->Business_unit }}">{{ $Bu->Business_unit}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>           
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="Orglevel1" id="Orglevel1" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Orglevel1</option>
                @foreach($Orglevel1_name as $org1)
                <option value="{{ $org1->Orglevel1 }}">{{ $org1->Orglevel1 }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>           
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="Role" id="Role" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Role</option>
                @foreach($Role_name as $Role)
                <option value="{{ $Role->Role }}">{{ $Role->Role }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>           
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary rounded" type="button" id="search" name="search">Apply</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary rounded" type="button" id="reset" name="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="members_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Employee ID
                </th>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Role
                </th>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Region
                </th>
                <th style="width: 12%">
                  Org Level1
                </th>
                <th style="width: 12%">
                   Org Level2
                </th>
                <th style="width: 12%">
                   Riskzone
                </th>
                <th style="width: 12%">
                   Probablity
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    fill_datatable();

    function fill_datatable(Business_unit = '', Orglevel1 = '', Role = '')
    {
        var dataTable = $('#members_data').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax:{
                url: "{{ route('test.index') }}",
                data:{Business_unit:Business_unit,Orglevel1:Orglevel1,Role:Role}
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'membersid',
                    name: 'membersid'
                },
                {
                    data:'Role',
                    name:'Role'
                },
                {
                    data:'Region',
                    name:'Region'
                },
                {
                    data:'Orglevel1',
                    name:'Orglevel1'
                },
                {
                    data:'Orglevel2',
                    name:'Orglevel2'
                },
                {
                    data:'Riskzone',
                    name:'Riskzone'
                },
                {
                    data:'Probablity',
                    name:'Probablity'
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    $('#search').click(function(){
        var Business_unit = $('#Business_unit').val();
        var Role = $('#Role').val();
        var Orglevel1 = $('#Orglevel1').val();

        if(Business_unit != '' && Orglevel1 != '' && Role != '')
        {
            $('#members_data').DataTable().destroy();
            fill_datatable(Business_unit,Orglevel1,Role);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Select filter option');
        }
    });

    $('#reset').click(function(){
        $('#Business_unit').val('');
        $('#Role').val('');
        $('#Orglevel1').val('');
        $('#members_data').DataTable().destroy();
        fill_datatable();
    });
    $("#members_data tbody tr").each(function() {
        alert($(this).find("td:first-child").html());
    });
    $('#members_data').on('click', 'tbody td', function(){
   window.location = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0) a').attr('href');
});

});
</script>

 @endsection
```

Comment: Can you show your controller code

Comment: Are you sure `.find('td:eq(0) a').attr('{{ route('Membersdetails.show') }}')` should not be something like `.find('td:eq(0) a').attr('href')`?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Initially it was .find('td:eq(0) a').attr('href') I modified this to check

Comment: @YasinPatel I have edited the question and added the controller code

Comment: @YasinPatel Updated my controller code

Comment: @prashant, Can you show your view code where you are creating link for details page.

Comment: @YasinPatel updated question with my view..please check